# Bypass control flow in do-while

Tags: loops, iteration, do-while

In case of "for" and "while", we can bypass the loop by placing the separator ";" for example in

`for(int i=0;i<=9;i++);`

`{`

`\\statements`

`}`

the control doesn't go inside the loop. Is such a thing possible in do-while?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.

According to [C++ syntax definition](http://www.externsoft.ch/download/cpp-iso.html#iteration_statement), a do-while is:

**'do' statement 'while' '(' expression ')' ';'**

So you could write:

```
do ;
while (...);
```

but not:

```
do ;
{
...
}
while (...);
```

Anyway, the remaining while would likely not behave as intended.